# Cannot hide the windows with 2nd click

Tags: javascript, html

I click on the button in red rectangle to show the windows. Now, if want want to close the windows, i just click on other part of the grey bar. What I want to do is to modify the code to click the button in red rectangle 2nd time to close the windows, but it does not work.

[image]

I have put the html and related files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p6rjawzk8t8igyp/AABLH6PeYRPdRnx-wJzKJYD7a?dl=0).

The main html is `chat.html`, where the main javascript lies in

```
assets\plugins\emojiarea\jquery.emojiarea.js
```

Following is portion of the code:

```
EmojiMenu.prototype.hide = function(callback) {
    if (this.emojiarea) {
        this.emojiarea.menu = null;
        this.emojiarea.$button.removeClass('on');
        this.emojiarea = null;
    }
    this.visible = false;
    this.$menu.hide();
};

EmojiMenu.prototype.show = function(emojiarea) {
    if (this.emojiarea && this.emojiarea === emojiarea) return;
    this.emojiarea = emojiarea;
    this.emojiarea.menu = this;

    this.reposition();
    this.$menu.show();
    this.visible = true;
};
```

I try to use `this.visible` to detect the whether the windows has been opened, if yes, then close it, but it does not work out. Is there a possibility to make the windows closed when I click the button in red rectangle 2nd time?

Comment: you could use toggle()

Comment: do you want to hide it only on button click?

Comment: @a1626 yes, first click show, second click close, third click open...and click on elsewhere it won't have any effect.

Comment: @RakeshGR not really, the code jquery.emojiarea.js controls the behavior :(

Comment: @william007 and you are not allowed to modify it?

Comment: @RakeshGR Can, but found not way to change the behavior, all files is at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p6rjawzk8t8igyp/AABLH6PeYRPdRnx-wJzKJYD7a?dl=0

Comment: `this.emojiarea.$button.addClass('on');` to `show` in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

So I went through the plugin. This piece of code:
    `$body.on('mouseup', function() {
            self.hide();
        });`

is why you couldn't use this.visible to check if it was already open or not,because every time you click on the button too this mouseup is triggered effectively hiding and then showing the popup.

Right after this:
`$button.on('click', function(e) {
            EmojiMenu.show(self);
            e.stopPropagation();
        });`
Add this:
`$button.on('mouseup', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });`
This will prevent the bubbling of the mouseup event from the button itself.
Now you can use "this.visible to detect the whether the windows has been opened, if yes, then close it."